# Batch CREATE table in Python for Oracle with Rollback on failure

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to create a set of tables in oracle dynamically using Python cx_Oracle connector. 
Here is what I have  :

```
#dynamically obtained create table queries
query_list = ['CREATE TABLE TABLE1(...','CREATE TABLE TABLE2(...','...']

try:
getConnection()
c = con.cursor()
for query in query_list:
   c.execute(query)
con.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The tables are being created fine.But I want to rollback / drop tables already created if the batch execution fails mid way. Since DDL queries auto commit on execution, is there a workaround so that either all tables are created or none.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "rollback" a DDL.  you can however detect if the table already exists, with something like:

```
SELECT count(*)  FROM user_tables where table_name = 'TABLE1';
```

loop through all the tables and if the sum of count(*) <> 0 then one or more tables exists, and you can drop it.

Comment: is there a better way to do it? I was looking for a way so that the table creation starts only after all statements are checked for error.

Comment: create two separate loops -1st one to check the existence, then 2nd one to create the tables. Also  just curious why you need to repeatedly drop and re-create the same tables.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. I am parsing the table name and table schemas from an external source and generating create table queries. The query list will be different every time.

Comment: Also I don't want to drop any existing tables. What I want to do is  - parse external schema definations, generate Oracle create table queries for them, then execute them in a batch if there are no errors in this set of queries.

Comment: Then do it in two loops as suggested.